# Graph API 2.3: <id>/Likes Requires Read_Stream?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want users to like certain posts they are looking that. To do that I call `<id>/likes` as a POST-method.

The user has these permissions: basic_info, public_profile, **publish_actions**, read_custom_friendlists, user_friends, user_photos, **user_posts**

I load the posts using `/feed/me`, which should mean that Facebook will find those posts using their ids in subsequent calls.

The traffic to `likes` looks like this:

```
POST /v2.3/123456789012345_987654321098765/likes HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Authorization: Bearer blahblah...
User-Agent: Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.11.0-beta (gzip)
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host: graph.facebook.com
Connection: Keep-Alive

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8
WWW-Authenticate: OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_request" "(#100) Error finding the requested story"
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-FB-Rev: 1694181
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-store
Facebook-API-Version: v2.3
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
X-FB-Debug: Ttvq+Mie2nN3jFdxREVlQj9pbZKanHPBUdlgNnOicrpDtOvEsrPOtoaKuQ+3w7TcG2L4lbWOLKhuDh4Zm14jlw==
Date: Fri, 17 Apr 2015 07:55:08 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 99

{"error":{"message":"(#100) Error finding the requested story","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}"
```

I tried to make it work with Graph API Explorer. I added permission `user_likes`, but that didn't make it work. I added permission `read_stream` and suddenly it worked!

However, according to the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/object/likes) the user only needs `publish_actions` to like a post.

As we won't get `read_stream` we are stuck with what the documentation offers. Is this a bug or do we need other permissions or a different logic to make it work?

Comment: I think the user needs to be able to “see” the object to be able to like it. And depending on what kind of post you are trying to like, `read_stream` might be needed for that. (The message “Error finding the requested story” indicates that the user is not able to see the post through your app.)

Comment: @CBroe Sorry, I forgot to say that Facebook returned that post in a call to "/feed/me". Hence, the user sees it and IMHO should also be able to like it.

Comment: That id looks like the combination of user id and post id. Try using only the last part of it after the underscore.

Comment: @CBroe Same thing. As I said it works when I add the `read_stream` permission. The post is there.

Comment: Then I suggest you go file a bug report about this, https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: @CBroe [Done](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1409239492728666/), a similar tickets exists for GET. I'm amazed they need a ticket for each HTTP-method. They should write tests and run them.

Comment: @sjngm, can you post here the link to your bug report?

Comment: @corvuszero Click on Done ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was [fixed by Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1409239492728666/). Note however, that `publish_actions` alone won't do it for the various types of posts. E.g. if you want to like videos the user also **must have** the `user_videos` permission even though you don't want to play them.

On a further note, Facebook obviously does NOT use SO for technical things.